# Pass data from text file loaded from the server to a JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript

Here's what I wanted to do. 
1. Load a text file (server side) say testJSON.txt [DONE]
2. Load the content from text file [DONE]
3. Dump the loaded data into an array for JavaScript [??HOW??]

Code snippet :

```
var data2, externalData;
$.get("testJSON.txt",function(externalData){
// Pop an alert showing the typeof the object taken from text file [WORKS]
alert("Data from JavaScript file: " + externalData + "typeof object " + typeof externalData);
// Convert the string from text file into JavaScript array [WORKS]
data2 = eval('['+ externalData + ']');
});
// **DOESN'T WORK**
alert(data2);
```

Comment: `$.get` is async.. you're trying to access `data2` while the call is in progress.. you need to use another callback or do your work in the provided callback from `get`

Comment: What are you using on the server side?

Comment: I just have a text file, plain JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: @tymeJV, how do I do it?

Comment: I didn't mark this as a duplicate-- I marked it as not clear what OP was asking.  You can't load stuff from the file system into javascript on the server if you don't have code on the server side.

Comment: @ps2goat, The code is on the server side, actually everything is on the client side, I am merely loading the web page. Is there a solution to this? So far not really luck to have a solution yet.